Calling Garbage Collector after reading & comparing a huge files
Hello with following code:
private void CompareFiles(string localPath, string remotePath, in ConcurrentBag<FileInfo> filesToUpdate, string partPath)
{
    var localFiles = new Dictionary<string, FileInfo>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    using (var localStream = new StreamReader(localPath, Encoding.UTF8))
    using (var remoteStream = new StreamReader(remotePath, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string? localLine;
        while ((localLine = localStream.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var localFileInfo = ParseInfoLine(localLine.AsSpan());
            if (localFileInfo.HasValue)
            {
                localFiles[localFileInfo.Value.Path] = localFileInfo.Value;
                localLine = null;
                localFileInfo = null;
            }
        }

        string? remoteLine;
        while ((remoteLine = remoteStream.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var remoteFileInfo = ParseInfoLine(remoteLine.AsSpan());
            if (remoteFileInfo.HasValue)
            {
                if (!localFiles.TryGetValue(remoteFileInfo.Value.Path, out var localFileInfo) ||
                    localFileInfo.Checksum != remoteFileInfo.Value.Checksum)
                {
                    filesToUpdate.Add(AddPartToFileInfo(remoteFileInfo.Value, in partPath));
                    remoteLine = null;
                    remoteFileInfo = null;
                }
            }
        }

        localStream.Close();
        remoteStream.Close();
    }
   
    //GC.Collect();
    //GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}

I'm wondering if calling GC.Collect() after finish is good option, because I'm comparing many files with contents about 1 million lines, and I know that the "parsed" data is no longer needed after, because I create from it other type of objects.
Without the GC, there is a problem with RAM grow during the action...
What do you think about that?
What I can do instead of that?
During the debugging GC is quite lazy and it waits until the app memory usage grows and grows... It's caused of course because of the line reading and parsing.

Are you actually seeing a problem? The data is already collectable (the individual lines, pretty much immediately, although the dictionary obviously will loiter for the entire comparison) - are you actively seeing RAM problems in this/other processes? Usually, you should leave the GC alone unless you have a specific reason, which you haven't mentioned.

After repeating an action memory grows to 2,1GB of RAM usage, then it's stabilizes... But  I know that it could stay on "ground" level like less than 200MB with that many data as I process, of course when I uncomment the GC.Collect() line.

have you enabled server GC? https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector ; or tried the background GC option?

I've prepared file called runtimeconfig.json, put in my project, added to .csproj but not sure if it's applied...

A little bit offtopic, but: maybe you could use System.IO.Pipelines (and reuse buffers) instead ReadLine() which creates new string for every line

Do you have any example of that?
